# Sci-Fi Science: Ramifications of Photon-to-Axion Conversion

Tags: technology, science-fiction

I'm considering what consequences would come from the development of hypothetical devices that could convert photons to axions at cost and power requirements accessible to governments, large businesses, and wealthier individuals. Three things come to mind:

1. Stealth capabilities and observability, at the cost of not being able to communicate or see very well
2. Heat management: radiant photons are now axions that hardly interact with anything at all
3. Discreet communication, assuming one has a partner that can convert axions to photons

I'm curious if I'm overlooking or not understanding unintended consequences of such a technology, and also wondering what "knobs to turn" there are to make this more easily balanced. For instance, what if there was a floor or ceiling for wavelength that could be converted? If only gammas or long wavelengths could escape the device's field, for instance, that does allow some, albeit flawed, detection. This would certainly help anyone inside of such a field see out of it if they had the right instruments!

Finally, besides very intense magnetic fields, does any other process or mechanism come to mind, such as exotic metamaterials?

Comment: What's their mass? Could be used to supplement the thrust of light propulsion.

Comment: Probably the same as the photons going in, so it wouldn't give you anything over a photon rocket in the first place except lower observability.

Comment: @cthon I think maybe what EDP is getting at is that if axions have mass>0 and speed<c then an axion rocket has lower exhaust velocity and higher thrust. Photon rockets could switch to a less efficient mode where more energy is spent to achieve much higher thrust.

Comment: I don't think that would really help much since the momentum would have to be conserved. You're not losing more mass and thus having a lower isp and higher thrust by doing this, you're just converting photons to axions within a field after they've already imparted momentum to the ship, unless you have some way to push on the axions as they leave your conversion field, which I believe is practically impossible.

Comment: @cthon if it's a process like neutrinos flipping, then intrinsic energy stays the same, no new momentum to steal. (Although photon energy is frame-dependent, so one wonders how the new axions decide how much intrinsic energy they now have.) If the process is like photon+??? -> axion, where ??? is energy stolen from the field (from a particle or other form), then there's higher energy in the axion, some of which is locked up intrinsically in mass which is better at trading momentum.

Comment: If the new mass is small like neutrinos, or the process produces an axion with exactly the photon energy and another waste particle carrying away the extra, then yeah not worth it. (Note: not an expert, and not familiar with the intense magnetic field effect you alluded to.) (Edit: the [Primakoff effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primakoff_effect).)

Comment: @Escapeddentalpatient. Converting photons to massive particles *always* reduces the thrust of a rocket. Ideally, to get maximum thrust, you'd convert your fuel completely into photons, because photons have a higher momentum-to-energy ratio than any massive particle.

Comment: I should a nuanced clarification: one should not forget that conventional rockets lose mass as they throw their propellant (part of the mass of the original rocket) backward to move the rest of the rocket forward. If you're getting thrust without reducing your own mass, changing the mass of the particles after they've stopped imparting momentum wouldn't do much at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've contemplated a similar idea, although mine was a field that turned all baryons to dark matter too, not just photons. Here's a couple ideas:

1. If "shields" using the photon-axion principle could be made, and if the photon energy interaction range is narrow, then that'd give some meaning to the popular sci-fi phrase "tuning the shields to the enemy's laser frequency". Free electron lasers can cycle through a wide range of frequencies, plus the use of non-linear crystals to do sudden frequency shifting, i.e., halving, doubling, tripling.
2. One of the greatest challenges with torchship engines like fusion or antimatter is the massive flux of hard radiation, which adds a lot of mass and complexity, shielding engine components and the rest of the ship. In a [gamma ray photon rocket](https://vixra.org/pdf/1201.0026v1.pdf), the only radiation is gamma. Such a device could maybe neutralize most of the errant radiation in the places that matter most, cutting down on redundant shielding and boosting efficiency.
   Hypothetically, if the device works well enough to neutralize photon rocket exhaust (and this is an idea taken from my own universe), you could put the engine *inside* the ship, tucked away from enemy fire behind an armored hull, while giving the outside impression of a reactionless drive system.

Comment: "Lasers will do jack squat" is a great point!

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see how you justify any of these. Axions are *hypothetical* particles which might resolve the strong CP Symmetry problem.

The Axion, by definition, does not interact with the electromagnetic field. So like, were does the Stealth come from ? Being able to make Axions out of Photons will do nothing to reduce your visibility.

Heat management as well is sus. Heat is a field as well and we have no real concept of how Axions would interact with that one. All we know that, as a dark matter candidate, it is not radiating any heat.

Communication I can see, but why should it be any better than Photons ? If anything it would be worse. In your world, Axions would presumably be dark matter. In which case, there are a lot of Axions out there considering their mass is so low.

Maybe i am missing something here but i dont see how any of the points you listed are actually improved / done with Axions.

Comment: Regarding your first point, OP appears to be using a model of axions that interact via the [Primakoff effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primakoff_effect). In regards to heat management, I think maybe what OP had in mind was using the axion conversion field device to "discard" radiated waste heat (thermal photons).

Comment: Regarding the Primakoff thing, fair enough. The issue with Heat management is that OP suggests converting Photons to Axions, which will happen in accordance with E = mc² because photons are massless, while Axions are not. Mass to Energy conversion is not efficient. Even black holes just manage ~80% if some people are to be belived.

Comment: Photons have momentum. You don't need to have a _rest mass_ for photons to convert to anything else. I'm also not asking for permission for go what if in a sci-fi, I'm asking "what if it did, then what?"

Comment: @cthon yeah they do, not a lot though. And nobody is talking about permission other than you. My point is that it does not seem like the usage of Axions is motivated beyond the name.

Comment: In order: Yes, hypothetical, in a what-if scenario for a scifi. The point is to convert photons which we can detect into axions which we really can't detect well at all. Thermal photons being turned into something that does not interact would be a way to dump radiant heat. The point was postulating a reverse process to turn axions back into photons for detection and thus communication.

Comment: @cthon Why exactly couldn't you detect axions if there is a method to make them ? Isn't this a mutually exclusive thing ? How would you know you made them if you cant detect them ? Dumping heat into them seems like an extra step if anything. If the heat is already in the form of a Photon, why do you waste efficiency to convert them again ?

Comment: The assumption is "photon to axion conversion exists, but it's expensive". If I then assume the reverse is possible, and know the format of a signal, and someone's pointing the axions at me, I can use that reverse process. The point isn't to run the converter forever and try to tease every possible signal out, but I suppose a state actor could. With regards to waste heat, I mean very hot radiators that would glow in visible light. Such a device would in practical terms make radiant heat disappear.

Comment: @cthon i just dont see the reason to doing any of this. It seems like using Axions is way of jumping through several hoops to achieve the same goal in a slightly worse way. Like, why would you care about visible radiation ? IR sensors are a thing. Even if you convert all radiant heat into Axions, what is stopping the enemy from building big Axion detectors ?

Comment: I'm seeking ramifications of the technology if it happens to exist. If I have this, I can have visual stealth, AND ir stealth, unless it only works over a small bandwidth. If it's comprehensive, you're blind! If you can tune the band gap, what band gap would you pick? And so on. 

The issue with axion detectors is that if they exist, the universe is swimming with them anyway, and it wouldn't easily be a worthwhile signal in most cases. It is, however, conceivable that a signal could be sent and received, albeit with low bandwidth and a high power requirement.

Comment: And i am telling you the ramifications are it doesn't work D: Like, if you can make Axions you can detect them. No stealth. Waste of energy, if you want stealth idk build a directional radiator system and like a chunky cooling system. If you dumb all the energy into Axions, guess what you will just glow in the "Axion band".